# SwiftUI how to change font and color for email address in Text

Tags: text, swiftui, verbatim-string, verbatim

If I didn't use verbatim with Text

Ex:

```
Text("Reach out to us on info@eyva.io for any queries!")
                    .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                    .font(Font.custom("Poppins-Regular", size: getFontSize(value: 16)))
```

Output:

[image: Outpuy]

And, if I used **verbatim** with

```
Text(verbatim: "Reach out to us on info@eyva.io for any queries!")
```

Ex:

```
Text(verbatim: "Reach out to us on info@eyva.io for any queries!")
                    .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                    .font(Font.custom("Poppins-Regular", size: getFontSize(value: 16)))
```

Output:

[image: Output 2]

Email clickable functionality not working if I used verbatim with `Text()`

I want to with email clickable.

[image: clickable]

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code It will help you:

```
  Text(.init("Reach out to us on [cinfo@eyva.io](cinfo@eyva.io) for any queries!"))
        .accentColor(.red)
```

here in the () round bracket, you have to write the link and in [] square bracket the respective text you want to see, here you want to show the email so in both brackets I wrote the email id modify as you want.

Answer (score 0):

Jatin's solution also works if you just want to display an email address in your desired color:
Text(.init("myemail@emailaddress.com")).font(.callout).accentColor(Color.white)